# Is it possible to recover the original objective function from a final simplex tableau?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I have a problem that I couldn't find an answer here.

I would like to know if it is possible, given a final simplex tableau for a maximization problem, to recover the original coefficients of the objetive function. If is is, how to proceed?

More specifically, this is the tableau:

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is $\theta$ in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take variable $x_6$ for instance. Its reduced cost equals $\hat{c}_6= -2$, and by definition
$$
\hat{c}_6 = c_6 - \pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\c_3} \cdot \pmatrix{1/2\\-1\\5} = 0 - \frac{c_1}{2}-c_2+5c_3
$$
Write the same equations for the $2$ other slack variables and solve the set of equations for $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$.

Comment: I think that the equation would be: $$\hat{c}_6 = c_6 - \pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\c_3}B^{-1} \cdot \pmatrix{1/2\\-1\\5}$$ But I got your point. Thanks so much.